# How to check two or more parameters from related models?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

There are these models defined as base structures:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
   product_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, default=0, primary_key=True)
   product_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='Generic Product')

   def __str__(self):
       return self.product_id


class ShoppingList(models.Model):
   shop_list_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=0, primary_key=True)
   shop_list_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default=0)
   product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
   session_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, default=0)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.shop_list_id
```

And there is another model that is used for **checking** if a `Product` and/or `ShoppingList` exist:

```py
class ShopListCheck(models.Model):
   product_id = models.ForeignKey(ShoppingList, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
   shop_list_id = models.OneToOneField(ShoppingList, related_name='sid',
                                       on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
   request_creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

   def session_id(self):
      return self.product_id.session_id

   def shop_list_id(self):
      return self.product_id.shop_list_id

   def __str__(self):
      return self.product_id
```

Serializers are defined this way:

```py
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = Product
      fields = '__all__'


class ShoppingListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = ShoppingList
      fields = '__all__'


class ShopListCheckSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   session_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   link = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   class Meta:
      model = ShopListCheck
      fields = ('product_id', 'shop_list_id', 'session_id',
                'request_creation_date', 'link')

   def get_session_id(self, obj):
      return obj.product_id.session_id

   def get_link(self, obj):
      return 'http://example.com/' + str(obj.product_id)
              + '/?session_id=' + str(obj.session_id())
```

Now I can send a POST request containing `product_id` to the `ShopListCheck` endpoint and I get all the `product_id`, `shop_list_id`, `session_id`, etc. (or error 400 if there's no given `product_id` in the dababase) in response.

What to do when I also want to check in the same request if given `shop_list_id` exists (or set "0" when I don't care about that)?

BTW, do you know any good resources I could practice this kind of relationships between models?

Answer (score 1):

You can override `is_valid` method of drf serializers to do field-level validation on `shop_list_id` and also set that field afterwards. You can check the documentation from [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation).